# Find number from string character matching its pattern

Tags: c#

Hello i got a string character pattern like bellow. Whole characters are always static like `[[demo.waka=number]]`. I want to grab the number from this pattern. Please check what i already tried. Problem with my existing solution is this only grabs `3` not whole number. What i want is it will grab after `[[demo.waka=` until end which is `]]`. Whats the best way to do this?

```
string foo = [[demo.waka=340]]
//need output just the number 340
```

already tried like bellow:

```
string foo = "[[demo.waka=340]]";
string a = foo.Substring(foo.LastIndexOf('=') + 1);
string b = a.Substring(0, 1);
int outputNumber = Convert.ToInt32(b);
```

Comment: `string outputString = Regex.Match(foo, @"\d+").Value`

Comment: @UlugbekUmirov your regex not finding for character  `[[demo.waka=` and `]]` which is my goal also. Because this character will be find from other mixed string characters. So don't want to miss match using this short regex

Comment: That was not specified in original problem definition. Nevertheless, `@"(?<=\[\[demo\.waka=)\d+(?=\]\])"` should help you.

Comment: yes..thanks. this one is perfect @UlugbekUmirov

Comment: and what about: `int outputNumber = Convert.ToInt32(foo.Replace("[[demo.waka=", "").Replace("]]", ""));` ? Will it really be slower, or more efficient, than this regular expression thing?

Comment: @Luuk yes good1 also. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Replace` seems to work 'faster':

```
    string foo = "[[demo.waka=340]]";
    DateTime start;

    for (int y = 0; y < 5; y++)
    {
        start = DateTime.Now;
        for (int x = 0; x < 10000; x++)
        {
            string outputString2 = Regex.Match(foo, @"(?<=\[\[demo\.waka=)\d+(?=\]\])").Value;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("1: {0}", (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds);

        start = DateTime.Now;
        for (int x = 0; x < 10000; x++)
        {
            int outputNumber3 = Convert.ToInt32(foo.Replace("[[demo.waka=", "").Replace("]]", ""));
        }
        Console.WriteLine("2: {0}", (DateTime.Now - start).TotalMilliseconds);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
```

Output:

```
1: 15,0234
2: 1,0008
1: 9,0035
2: 1,9725
1: 7,9981
2: 1,9988
1: 8,0316
2: 1,9694
1: 9,0298
2: 1,0002
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work with string like "Hello world 123! [[demo.waka=340]] Bye-bye world 456!"